# cobertura-maven-plugin with Java 8

Tags: java, maven, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

Is it just me or the cobertura-maven-plugin doesn't work with java 8? when it runs I get

```
[INFO] --- cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:instrument (default) @ provider-impl ---
[INFO] Cobertura 2.0.3 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
[cobertura] WARN  [main] net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter - Unable to instrument file /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BranchBuilder/implementations/provider-impl/target/generated-classes/cobertura/com/foo/impl/internal/ServiceProviderImpl$JoinRunner.class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:147)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.instrumentClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:121)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.CoberturaInstrumenter.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(CoberturaInstrumenter.java:234)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentationToSingleClass(Main.java:298)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.addInstrumentation(Main.java:307)
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.instrument.Main.parseArguments(Main.java:399)
```

I know there were issues with ASM and java 8 so I suspect the issue is that the maven-plugin has not been updated to use a java-8 compatible version of ASM

For reference, I asked the question [here](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/166) but got no answer

Has anyone managed to use cobertura-maven-plugin with java 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an open issue to make it understand new classformat , 
https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/issues/21

Comment: ah, my query for "maven-cobertura-plugin java 8" didn't return that. I blame google ;)
thank you

Comment: This issue has been fixed now and is available in version `2.7`

Comment: Codehaus JIRA no longer exists. A similar github issue with some open references (streams and lambdas): https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/issues/21

Answer (score 18):

I was able to get it working by manually updating the ASM dependency used by the cobetura-maven-plugin.  Here is a link with more details:
http://www.befreeman.com/2014/09/getting-cobertura-code-coverage-with.html

Comment: Actually, as you start using the more exotic features of Java 8 more often, this workaround seems to stop working, unfortunately.  :(

Comment: @metaforge Please see https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/166#issuecomment-64662005 for a possible solution.  

Brian F this answer might be incomplete, you need to update other dependencies, please see my github link

Comment: Did not work for me when I used lambdas - is there a way to work around that as well?

Answer (score 3):

This also happens if you have a cobertura plugin in your `<build>` and `<reporting>` sections. Remove one and the problem will go away.